# How to export the views to csv using BCP with carriage- return/line-feed delimiting rows

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I wanted to export the data from the views to the CSV using the BCP Command, with carriage-
return/line-feed delimiting rows. For that, I have specified that in the XML format as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" LENGTH="9"  xsi:type="CharFixed" />
<FIELD ID="2" LENGTH="3"  xsi:type="CharFixed" />
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
</RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Id_ein_empr" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" LENGTH="9" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Emp_Loc_nbr" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" LENGTH="3" />
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And I am using this XML format in BCP query as:

For that, I have written the following query.

```
DECLARE 
@DATACmd VARCHAR(500), 
@FileLocation varchar(255), 
@FileName varchar(255), 
@StateCode varchar(2), 
@v_Out_file_path varchar(255), 
@v_Data_path varchar(255),
@header_format_path varchar(255),
@v_Header_path varchar(255),
@HeaderFileName varchar(255);

SET @FileLocation ='c:\csv\output'
SET @FileName = 'Araddis_'+FORMAT(Getdate(), 'MMddyyyy') + '.txt'
SET @v_Out_file_path = 'c:\csv\' + @StateCode + '\output\' + 'Output_' + @FileName  
SET @v_Data_path = @FileLocation + '\' + @FileName


SELECT  @DATACmd = 'bcp '  
                        + '"select * from Db_1.dbo.[Forms]"'  
                        + ' queryout ' + @FileLocation   
                        + '\' + @FileName 
                        + ' -f "C:\csv\Format_FL.xml" -T -S' + @@servername;  
SELECT  @DATACmd AS 'Command to execute';
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @DATACmd;
```

But this always give me an error as:

```
NULL
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Host-file columns may be skipped only when copying into the Server
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations
NULL
BCP copy out failed
NULL
```

when I didn't specify the `TERMINATOR="\r\n"` the query runs successfully but all the data will be in one line. So, how would I add the carraige-return with new line?

Comment: The error isn't anything to do with the presence or absence of the `TERMINATOR` attribute, it's that you have three `FIELD` definitions but only two `COLUMN` definitions. You should always have the same number of `FIELD` and `COLUMN` definitions. Just define the `TERMINATOR="\r\n"` attribute on the last field.

Comment: it requires xsi:type="CharTerm" and Id without that just adding `TERMINATOR="\r\n"` will give the error.